# Issues Implementing Halstead's Complexity Metrics

Tags: c++, c, metrics

I'm currently practicing with a simple program to understand the equations  involved in deriving various metrics from Halstead's software science. I do believe I'm doing it correctly, but I feel like I haven't registered all operands and operators so that I can start with the mathematics.

The program I'm using is:

```
/*01*/ // counts how many items in sArray[] are also in tArray[]
/*02*/ int matched(int sArray[], int tArray[], int sMax, int tMax)
/*03*/ {
/*04*/    int count, i, first, middle, last;
/*05*/ 
/*06*/    for (i = 0; i < sMax; ++i)
/*07*/    {
/*08*/        last = tMax - 1;
/*09*/        for (int first = 0; first <= last;)
/*10*/        {
/*11*/            middle = (first + last) / 2;
/*12*/            if (tArray[middle] == sArray[i])
/*13*/            {
/*14*/                 count++;
/*15*/                 break;
/*16*/            } 
/*17*/            if (tArray[middle] < sArray[i]) 
/*18*/            {
/*19*/                 first = middle + 1;
/*20*/            }
/*21*/            else
/*22*/            {
/*23*/                 last =  middle - 1;
/*24*/            }
/*25*/         }
/*26*/    }
/*27*/    return count;
/*28*/ }
```

And I've come out with

- n1 = the number of distinct operators  = 10
- n2 = the number of distinct operands = 9
- N1 = the total number of operators = 24
- N2 = the total number of operands = 34

These notes show the distinct operators and operands found:

> **Operators** 
>   = Assignment (line 6, 8, 9, 11, 19, 23) = 6 
>  < Less Than (line 6, 17) = 2 
>   ++ Increment (line 6, 14) = 2 
>   - Subtract (line 8, 23) = 2 
>  <= Less Than or Equal to (line 9) = 1 
>   + Addition (line 11, 19) = 2 
>  / Division (line 11) = 1 
>   == Equal to (line 12) = 1 
>  [] index (line 2*2, 12*2, 17*2 = 6 
>  break (line 15) = 1
>
> **Operands** 
>  count (line 4, 14) = 2 
>  i (line 4, 6*3, 12, 17) = 6 
>  first (line 4, 9*2, 11, 19) = 5 
>  middle (line 4, 11, 12, 17, 19, 23) = 6 
>  last (line 4, 8, 9, 11, 23) = 5 
>  sArray (line
>   2, 12, 17) = 3 
>  tArray (line 2, 12, 17) = 3 
>  sMax (line 2, 6)
>   = 2 
>  tMax (line 2, 8) = 2

Is there anything vital I've missed out? From my understanding:

1. Operands are values
2. Operators manipulate and check operands

Comment: Please don't put line numbers in code snippets. If you want to draw attention to a specific line then put e.g. a comment on that line.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg In the context of this question, it's more plausible to link the line numbers to the notes below it. Theres no expectation of the reader executing the code, it's for software testing to find the number of operators and operands, so for this question I feel it helps the reader quickly scan through it easily, whether it's a comment or not. I don't think you read the question in it's entireity, it would make no difference,

Comment: I don't know the metrics, but are pre- and post-increment considered the same or distinct?  You've got both.

Comment: I'm not sure if i'm honest, thats the kind of details i'm trying to work out. I would imagine they'd be distinct

Comment: pre- and post- increment mean same here.

Comment: I don't see how you can class `break` as an **operator** under your definition *"Operators manipulate and check operands"*

Comment: Unfortunately, thats from my understanding. Like i say, it could be more than wrong, any input @WeatherVane?

Comment: I was surprised not to find a third category: flow control, such as `break` and `return`. But on reflection I realised that `return` may have an operand, so I can see the two categories used here (and elsewhere) refer to elements that instruct what to do, and elements that specify an object. I'll risk another comment: a program that is rewritten to extract some commonly used lines of code as a function, will have a different metric from the original code although functionally identical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of Halstead's metrics is to answer a lot of questions like "How difficult is the code to read", "How much effort was put into writing the code", etc. The formula for Halstead's Difficulty metric should provide a hint on how the first question answered:

```
Difficulty = (Unique Operators / 2) * (Operands / Unique Operands);
```

You can see that having more unique operators, obviously, makes the code harder to read.

On braces: A lot of sources on the subject consider `{}` to be operators, which I don't see the point of. Curly braces act as a structure (punctuation) element and in a lot of ways makes code easier to understand, not harder. (Take, for example, conditional block with and without braces)

Counting the function name `matched` is relevant only in a more general context, but not when you measure the metrics of the function implementation (given there is no recursion).

On operators: counting operators can be tricky. For example, `[]` appearing in function declaration and `[]` on lines 12 and 17, are actually different things. The first one is array declaration, the second is `operator[]` - accessing element by index. The same with postfix and prefix `++`, having them both in the program makes it harder to read.

The same logic applies to language keywords: `for`, `if`, `else`, `break`, `return`. The more of them in the code the harder it is to read.

On types: type names in variable declaration is also tricky. Some attribute them to operators, some to operands. But if we look again at the Difficulty formula, we would see that type names would better go to operators, in the sense that having more different types in the code make it harder to read, not easier.

Your counts for operands seems to be alright.

```
Operators 
= Assignment (line 6, 8, 9, 11, 19, 23) = 6 
< Less Than (line 6, 17) = 2 
++ Prefix Increment (line 6) = 1
++ Postfix Increment (line 14) = 1 
- Subtract (line 8, 23) = 2 
<= Less Than or Equal to (line 9) = 1 
+ Addition (line 11, 19) = 2 
/ Division (line 11) = 1 
== Equal to (line 12) = 1
[] declaration (line 2) = 2 
[] index (line 12, 17) = 4
for (line 6, 9) = 2
if (line 12, 17) = 2
else (line 21) = 1
break (line 15) = 1
return (line 27) = 1
int declaration = 7

Operands 
count (line 4, 14) = 2 
i (line 4, 6*3, 12, 17) = 6 
first (line 4, 9*2, 11, 19) = 5 
middle (line 4, 11, 12, 17, 19, 23) = 6 
last (line 4, 8, 9, 11, 23) = 5 
sArray (line 2, 12, 17) = 3 
tArray (line 2, 12, 17) = 3 
sMax (line 2, 6) = 2 
tMax (line 2, 8) = 2

Metrics
n1 = 17
n2 = 9
N1 = 37
N2 = 34
Difficulty = (n1 * N2) / (2 * n2) = 32.1
```

I was referring to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halstead_complexity_measures) and [this page on Virtual Machinery](http://www.virtualmachinery.com/sidebar2.htm).

By the way, most things said are my opinion, and may not coincide with more official sources.

By the way: 2, here is exact and strict definition on what should be counted as operators and operands in a C++ code: http://www.verifysoft.com/en_halstead_metrics.html.

Comment: Excellent clarification on the confusion I have had with operators and what I thought i knew about operands, Nicely Written too, Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, initialize count to 0 and next operators are not values they are variables.

```
operators 
matched -1
() -6
[] -6
{} -6
int -7
for -2
if -2
else -1
return -1
= -6 
< -2
<= -1
++ -2
- -2
+ -2
/ -1
== -1
break -1

operands
2 -line no. 11 -1
1 (8,19,23) -3
0 -1
count -3
i -6
first -5
middle -6
last -5
sArray -3
tArray -3
sMax -2
tMax -2

N1=50
N2=40
n1=18
n2=12
```

The book I am referring to is Software Metrics and Software Metrology By Alain Abran.
You can download it from here -> http://profs.etsmtl.ca/aabran/English/Accueil/ChapersBook/Abran%20-%20Chapter%20005.pdf

I hope it will solve all your doubts.

And function names,braces,type names,all other key words and all other well known operators come under operator section

Variables and constant values that are input to any functions or operators are operands.

Hence, I come up with this answer.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, I appreciate you putting the time in here, but have you anymore information as to why you have the outcome you have from any credible sources?

Comment: From what I learnt Functions braces are all operators and const numbers or characters are all operands, This doesn't mean only they are operators and operands.

Comment: And the book I am referring to is Software Metrics and Software Metrology
 By Alain Abran .

Comment: sorry buddy, i'm not as active as i once was. put the comments you've replied into the answe and +1 for the reccomendation of the book, i'll give that a read.

Comment: If my answer is enough to you can let me have the bounty you offered

Comment: Yes but you need to add the comments you've written into the answer in a reasonable manner so that users hwo wish to look further can understand without reading the comments, I won't be giving you 50 reputation without all the information being inside the answer, just edit it add the details you've already defined (including a link to the book online if possible and any other tips including how you came about the answer) if you need a hand, refer to stackoverflow's guide on how to answer a question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I still don't understand from your answer, how you got the outcome you got? you need to write in way more detail to show in depth knowledge for 50 rep. I want to know why, I'm not just looking for an answer to the distinct operands and operators, i want to know why, so i can put this into practice. This isn't homework, I should be learning from your answer. What have i done wrong? and why is it wrong?